# Protractor Chrome with XVFB on OSX

Tags: macos, selenium, gruntjs, protractor, xvfb

I want to run the Protractor E2E Test for my Angular Application on a Bamboo Linux Build Server using XFVB to run Chrome resp. Chromium headless, exactly like in this gist: https://gist.github.com/nwinkler/f0928740e7ae0e7477dd.

But first I wanted to check if it works on the OSX machine I'm developing on.

Question: Is this even possible on OSX and if yes, what am I doing wrong?

In my Gruntfile I have:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell-spawn');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-env');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-protractor-runner');
```

And:

```
protractor: {
        options: {
            configFile: "test/protractor.conf.js",
            keepAlive: false
        },
        run: {}
    },

    shell: {
        xvfb: {
            command: 'Xvfb :50 -ac -screen 0 1600x1200x24',
            options: {
                async: true
            }
        }
    },
    env: {
        xvfb: {
            DISPLAY: ':50'
        }
    }
```

And finally:

```
grunt.registerTask('protractor-xvfb', [
        'clean:server',
        'wiredep',
        'includeSource',
        'concurrent:server',
        'autoprefixer:server',
        'connect:e2e',
        'shell:xvfb',
        'env:xvfb',
        'protractor:run',
        'shell:xvfb:kill'
    ]);
```

(Do not mind the tasks up to shell:xvfb, they work)

And in my protractor.conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
framework: 'jasmine2',
seleniumServerJar: '../node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar',
seleniumPort: 4444,
chromeDriver: '../node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver',
troubleshoot: false,
basePath: '../',
specs: ['protractor/***/**/*.js'],
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9000',
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
}};
```

What this does at the moment is:

1. Serve the application on localhost:9000
2. Start xvfb asychnronuously in the background
3. Successfully start a standalone Selenium Server on localhost:4444:wd/hub
4. Open a Chrome window and successfully run the test.
5. As soon as the test is finished kill the xfvb process.

But I can't see any indices that Selenium actually connects to the xvfb framebuffer.

Comment: Are the tests failing? What output do you see from protractor/selenium? Can you run this w/o using Xvfb (ie- using the normal display) on your machine?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write that. There is a Selenium Standalone Server starting successfully and the test completes successfully in a newly opened Chrome window. This is on a Macbook Pro Mid 2012 OSX 10.10.2

Comment: I'm confused then. What are you expecting to see that you are not? Xvfb is a *virtual* frame buffer, so you should not see anything from that screen.

Comment: I can see a Chrome window opening on my screen and Protactor navigating through the application. I would not expect that to happen if Selenium was successfully connected to xvfb exactly because of the reason you described. I am expcecting no visual feedback from the test at all, no browser window, only feedback from Protractor on the command line. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are having is [described here](http://afitnerd.com/2011/09/06/headless-browser-testing-on-mac/).

Essentially, there is no virtual frame buffer support on Mac for browsers. Your best bet would be to try this again on a linux machine.  My guess is that this will work for you.